# Is curvature is the amount the tangent vector is turning in radians?

Tags: calculus

I was just thinking if the curvature is the degree a tangent vector of a curve is turning in radians, then that means if the value stays equal to 1 for $2\pi$ units of arc length then the curve should make circle in $2\pi$ units of arc length and if the curvature is 360 or 720 constantly then it would mean the curve makes 1 or 2 circles by 1 unit of arc length. Does it in fact measure the angle between one tangent vector and the subsequent one?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking

Comment: I was thinking bout what a point infinitesimally far in the direction of the normal vector measures again...

Comment: In your question you say "if the value of the curvature stays 1" then you say "if the curvature is 360 or 720." Why would you have a curvature value of 360?

Comment: If the curvature stays equal to 1 for $2\pi$ units of arc length then the curve makes a circle in $2\pi$ units of arc length. Similarly, f the curvature stays equal to 360 or 720 for $2\pi$ units of arc length then the curve makes 360 or 720 circles in $2\pi$ units of arc length.

Comment: Well- 360 degrees is approximately 6 radians: I might revise the question to "which does curvature measure in radians or degrees?"

Comment: I take it the measurement is in radians then!!

Comment: Yes, you’re right